# parseInt JavaScript Binary in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, binary

I've searched these forums and have found nothing. What I'm trying to find is a function in PHP that will convert a binary representation into a regular integer. parseInt seems to do the trick in JavaScript, but I need a serverside equivalent for the specific program I am creating. Anyone have thoughts?

i.e. `parseInt(110100101);` in JavaScript returns 421. I need a function that returns the same number with that binary.

Comment: Perhaps [bindec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php)

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant. I did not realize that that was a function.

Comment: In PHP 5.4, you can specify an integer in binary. Example: `0b01001110011010010110010101110100`

Answer (score 1):

bindec will do what you are looking for. You just need to make sure that you are passing it as a string, so if you have as an int, just cast it to a string first

```
$newInt = bindec( (string) $binaryInt );
```

Otherwise if its already a string you dont need to cast it to one and can just pass it in:

```
$newInt = bindec( $binaryString );
```